# Tips for locally debugging web pages that contain protocol relative URLs

Tags: javascript, http, https, protocols, relative-path

There is probably a better title for I'd like to accomplish, but the details should be helpful.

I've recently learned that specifying a script's `src` path as `//some.domain.com` rather than `http://some.domain.com` or `https://some.domain.com` will cause the browser to request the script using whichever protocol was used to load the page.  This works great when the page is loaded from a site, but often I debug on my local system, so the protocol is `file`, and of course errors occur whenever resources or scripts aren't found.

Other than changing src paths, is there a better way to debug locally?  I imagine there is code solution that detects when the page is running locally versus loaded from a domain, but I haven't found examples yet.

Comment: Is there a reason not to install the web server locally and debug via it? Apache can be installed in minutes, if you are not on Windows or don't want to deal with IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Install a product such as [wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), then you'll have a localhost webserver you can test everything on. This is how I do it, works like a charm.

There are similar products available for ASP or other non-PHP server-side technologies (you didn't specify), if you are just doing HTML + JS then any old server would do.